# Finding a holomorphic function with real part $u(x,y)=x+e^{-x}\cos y$ .

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> We are given the real part of a complex function: 
>   $$u(x,y)=x+e^{-x}\cos y.$$
>   We have to find a holomorphic complex function with this real part of the function also $f(0)=1$.

Solution:
$$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$
We find that:
$$u_{x}=1-e^{-x}\cos x;u_{xx}=e^{-x}\cos y,$$
$$u_{y}=-e^{-x}\sin y;u_{yy}=-e^{-x}\cos y,$$

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0.$$

From Cauchy-Riemann we find that $v=y-e^{-x}\sin y+\varphi(x)+C$ and $f(z)=(x+e^{-x})+i(y-e^{-x}\cos y+C)$

*And from here what do we have to do? How do we check the values of $f(0)=1$?*

Comment: well what is $f(0)$ for your function?

Comment: f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y), I made this change